# How To Use Yield Inside A Linq Query

Tags: c#, linq, yield

I have the following method:

```
    public string GetDepartmentTitle(string DepartmentAbbreviation) {
        List<TaxonomyItem> Divisions = TaxonomyFromCMS.GetAllItems(DomainDataConstants.DivisionAndDepartment.TAXONOMY_ID);
        List<TaxonomyItem> Departments = new List<TaxonomyItem>();

        Divisions.ForEach(delegate(TaxonomyItem Division) {
            Departments.AddRange(Division.SubTaxonomyItems);
        });

        TaxonomyItem Result = (from d in Departments
                               where d.Name == DepartmentAbbreviation
                               select d).FirstOrDefault();

        return Result == null ? "" : Result.Title;
    }
```

It first reads all of the Divisons (which there are only 3) but those divisions have many Departments below them as SubTaxonomyItems.  Currently I step through each of the Divisions and extract out each of the Departments and put them in a List called Departments.  Then I use Linq to search for the specific item.

It works great but I would love to skip/consume that first step of getting the sub items.  I have tried the following line that doesn't seem to work:

```
TaxonomyItem Result = (from d in Departments.SubTaxonomyItems
```

I then through perhaps some sort of lambda with a foreach of the Departments.SubTaxonomyItems that contains a yeild statement.  That may be the trick, but I couldn't get it to work.  Looking into the yeild statement it seems there can be a way if I make some extension method.  But I am wanting to see if it can be done inline and like the following pseudo code:

```
    public string GetDepartmentTitle(string DepartmentAbbreviation) {
        List<TaxonomyItem> Divisions = TaxonomyFromCMS.GetAllItems(DomainDataConstants.DivisionAndDepartment.TAXONOMY_ID);

        TaxonomyItem Result = (from d in Divisions.ForEach(delegate(TaxonomyItem Division) {
                                 yeild return Divison.SubTaxonomyItems;
                               }) AS Dps
                               where Dps.Name == DepartmentAbbreviation
                               select Dps).FirstOrDefault();

        return Result == null ? "" : Result.Title;
    }
```

Is this possible this way or some other way I am not seeing?  Can it even be done without an extension method?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First off, you can solve your problem easily by just adding another "from" to the query:

```
var query = from division in divisions
            from department in division.Departments
            where department.Name == whatever
            select department;
```

This does exactly what you were doing; it selects out the sequence of departments from each division, and glues all those sequences together to make one long sequence of departments.

This gives you a slick syntax for the "stitch together a bunch of sequences" scenario. More generally though, sometimes you run into this sort of situation:

```
var bars = from foo in foos
           some complicated query logic here
           select foo.bar;
var abcs = from bar in bars
           some other query logic here
           select bar.abc;
```

and you want to figure out how to make this into a single query. You can do that like this:

```
var abcs = from bar in (
               from foo in foos
               some complicated query logic here
               select foo.bar)
           some other query logic here
           select bar.abc;
```

which is *ugly*, or you can do this:

```
var abcs = from foo in foos
           some complicated query logic here
           select foo.bar into bar
           some other query logic here
           select bar.abc;
```

That does exactly the same thing but it is more pleasant to read. This syntax is called a "query continuation".

To answer your specific question: it is not legal to put a "yield return" in an anonymous method or lambda. This is quite unfortunate because it would be really useful. The transformations that the compiler performs to make anonymous functions and iterator blocks work are quite complex and thus far we have always punted on getting them to work together fully. (That is, you can put a lambda in an iterator block, but you can't put an iterator block in a lambda.) I hope, but do not promise, that some day we'll be able to fix this code up and allow iterator block lambdas. (Remember, Eric's musings about future language features are For Entertainment Purposes Only.)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you just want something like this.

```
public string GetDepartmentTitle(string DepartmentAbbreviation) {
    var items = TaxonomyFromCMS.GetAllItems(DomainDataConstants.DivisionAndDepartment.TAXONOMY_ID); 
    var result = items.SelectMany(item=>item.SubTaxonomyItems).FirstOrDefault(item=>item.Name == DepartmentAbbreviation);
    var text = result !=null  ? result.Title : String.Empty;
    return text;
}
```

Comment: Bloody 'ell you beat me to it!

Answer (score 1):

Yield return can only be used in very select (pun!) locations, and a Linq query isn't one of them.    Luckily you don't need it here.

```
var q = from division in Divisions
        from dps in division.SubTaxonomyItems
        where dps.Name == DepartmentAbbreviation
        select dps.Title;

return q.FirstOrDefault() ?? String.Empty;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just do:

```
var divisions = TaxonomyFromCMS.GetAllItems
                 (DomainDataConstants.DivisionAndDepartment.TAXONOMY_ID);

var titles = from division in divisions
             from deparment in division.SubTaxonomyItems
             where deparment.Name == DepartmentAbbreviation
             select deparment.Title;

return titles.FirstorDefault() ?? "";
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this linq you are looking for?

```
var Result = Divisions.SelectMany(d => d.SubTaxonomyItems).Where(subItem => subItem.Name == DepartmentAbbreviation).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: What is the type of "subItem" in your code? It appears to be a sequence of departments, but you're treating it as a department.

Comment: It's an item of Division.SubTaxonomyItems. Maybe I misunderstand his issue, please info me :) Thanks.

Comment: Right. The "Select" returns a *sequence* of *sequences of items*. You are assuming that the Select returns a *sequence of items* -- that it "flattens" the sequence of sequences -- but that's not what Select does; that's what SelectMany does. In your code each sequence in the sequence will be passed to "Where", so "subItem" will be a sequence of items, and a sequence of items doesn't have a Name. Each item has a Name.

Comment: Interesting. I checked the difference and you are exactly right. Select returns groups of the items while SelectMany selects single items from the condition. I'll remember this. Thanks.